# How do you pass variables to javascript and back from php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

```
//Javascript
function updateStudentAttendance(event)
  {
    if ($(this).hasClass('here')) {
  $(this).removeClass('here');
  $(this).addClass('absent');
  var schoolId = $(this).children('p').attr('id');
  var studentId = $(this).attr('id');
  var classId = document.getElementById("classId").value;
  postAttendance(studentId, schoolId, classId, 'Absent');
}

function postAttendance(studentId, schoolId, classId, attendanceEvent)
{
  $.post('post_attendance.php', {
  'studentId': studentId,
  'schoolId': schoolId,
  'event': attendanceEvent,
  'classId': classId
}, function(data) {
 // alert(data);
});
}

//php code looks like this:
<?php
    print sprintf('<div id="%s" class="student span2 well well-small %s">
        <input type="hidden" id="classId" name ="classId" value="%s">'
        , $student->getId(), $class, $classId);
    print '<img src="img/userp.png" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">';
    print sprintf('<p id="%s" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">%s %s'
        , $_GET['schoolId'], $student->getFirstName, $student->getLastSurname());               
    print '</p>';
    print '</div>';
?>
```

That's the code I'm using which which pulls the information from the id's and I had to add a hidden element to get the classId. I then post it back after it being modified to update the database with the new information. I feel like this is a terribly odd way to do it and would like to have a better solution for passing these variables.

Please let me know a better way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Cookies or echoed vars or hidden input fields. What you're doing is fine.

Comment: just write the variable to JS and then post?

Comment: I actually don't really know javascript well, I'm adapting someone elses code. how would you write it to JS?

Answer (score 2):

### to PHP

using jquery ajax or using form post

### to JS

using hidden input fields with json encoded value (if data stracture is complicated)

Answer (score 0):

There are two constructs that I think you can make use of.

One is the [HTML5 `dataset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), which allow you to store custom private data for web applications that is not part of the semantics of the markup.  This is more flexible than using `id` because you can only have one `id` and it has other purposes.  You can have multiple `class`es, but that too is difficult to use.

The second is the [`hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute, which declares that an element is not relevant to the page's current state / for use by the user.  I sometimes use this attribute to create elements that organize application data that is not relevant to the page markup (I hope this is a correct use, though, but I'm not positive).

Answer (score 0):

Within your jQuery [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) add some json datatype :

**jQuery**

```
 $.post('post_attendance.php', {data:value},
    dataType:"json"
}, function(data) {
   alert(data.error); //will be false
});
```

Than on your `post_attendance.php` echo your result with json_encode :

```
$array = array('response'=>'Some value', error => false);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an hidden input field and so store a encoded json.

```
$data = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2"
);
$input = "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"storage\" value=\"%s\" />";
printf($input, htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)));
```

On jQuery

```
var storage = $.parseJSON($("#storage").val());
```

Another way is using `data` attribute, these attributes can be accessed using `$("#element").data()`.

Do some cool changes:

```
storage["key1"] = "value3";
```

Back to PHP:

```
$.post("url.php", storage, function(){
   alert("Alright, bro");
})
```